# With WP_DEBUG_LOG set to true, no debug output shows in debug.log, why?

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress

I'm trying to enable basic debug output with WordPress for a plugin I'm developing. I managed to get some so far, but failed to redirect it to `wp-content/debug.log`. I've been roughly following [the guide by Douglas Neiner](http://fuelyourcoding.com/simple-debugging-with-wordpress/). Here's what I did:

I added this snippet of code to the end of `wp-config.php`:

```
@ini_set ('display_errors', 0);
define ('WP_DEBUG', true);
define ('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define ('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

I manually created `debug.log` file and made sure it's accessible by `www-data` user (I'm running WordPress locally, on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
septi@norbert:~$ sudo su www-data -c 'ls -l /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/debug.log'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 0 Dec  9 22:12 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/debug.log
septi@norbert:~$ sudo su www-data -c 'ls -l /srv/www/localhost/wp-content/debug.log'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 0 Dec  9 22:12 /srv/www/localhost/wp-content/debug.log
septi@norbert:~$ sudo su www-data -c 'echo i can write >> /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/debug.log'
septi@norbert:~$
```

Added a few supposed debug output statement inside the plugin activation hook, as well as the intentional error:

```
include ('i fail wp');

register_activation_hook (__FILE__, 'hello_world_activate');

function hello_world_activate()
{
    error_log ('I love debug output when it works!');
}
```

What I expect is an error message about the missing include file in `debug.log` along with the "I love debug output when it works!" message, and nothing on the page. What I get is the missing include file on the page message and nothing in `debug.log`. The debug output message is not fully lost, however. I found it in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Sun Dec 09 22:58:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(i fail wp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/helloworld2085/helloworld2085.php on line 28, referer: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
[Sun Dec 09 22:58:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'i fail wp' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/helloworld2085/helloworld2085.php on line 28, referer: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
[Sun Dec 09 22:58:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] I love debug output when it works!, referer: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
[Sun Dec 09 22:58:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(i fail wp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/helloworld2085/helloworld2085.php on line 28, referer: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
[Sun Dec 09 22:58:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'i fail wp' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/helloworld2085/helloworld2085.php on line 28, referer: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
```

I suspect that the `error_log()` function is not the right one to use to output to `debug.log`, but I failed to find the right way. Oh, of course I could just hardcode the file path and append to it, but, you know...

Comment: same problem here. Everything is ON, no errors shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error_log() function writes to the web server's error log (e.g. /var/log/httpd/error_log); what you want is [trigger_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: This is not always correct!  I have been using `error_log()` to write to the debug log.  I'm currently looking for a reason as to why (with apparently the same configuration) the `error_log()` messages have suddenly started going to the apache2 error log instead of the debug log.

Comment: False. By adding define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); to wp-config this should result in desired behavior. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with WordPress running in Apache 2.4 on Fedora 19. Output of error_log() was landing in /var/log/httpd/error_log instead of wp-content/debug.log. Httpd process had write permission (+775) to /var/www/html/wp-content directory, but it was unable to create the wp-content/debug.log file.

My wp-config.php debug setting was:

```
@ini_set(‘display_errors’,0);
define('WP_DEBUG',         true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

As it turned out, the real cause was SELinux. I made SELinux policy change and allowed httpd to write to wp-content with following commands. (Refer SELinux Troubleshooter to get the actual command for your installation)

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/wp-content'
restorecon -v '/var/www/html/wp-content'
```

After this debug messages start appearing in wp-content/debug.log.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error. What I did was to first create the debug.log file under the wp-content directory. I realized that errors were not logging in this file. Eventually, I decided to change the permission for this file (right-click on the created debug.log file in cPanel, and click on Change Permissions). I changed to 777 (This enables write rule for the file).

I hope it helps!